# Accessing MacOS X clipboard from

Tags: macos, vim, osx-mountain-lion, clipboard

I'd like to access the system clipboard in Mountain Lion as a register in vim.

The vim that comes with Mountain Lion is built with -xterm_clipboard shown in vim --version. Homebrew has a formula for vim in the dupes collection that also builds with -xterm_clipboard. After editing the formula I'm now building vim with +xterm_clipboard. However, going into vim and using :reg to see the registers doesn't show the contents of the system clipboard in any register.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want vim compiled with xterm-cliboard support. You want vim to be compiled with clipboard support.

After you get clipboard support compiled in you should see the system clipboard in `*` and `+`